# Understanding Autofs mounting

Tags: mount, automounting, autofs

So my auto.master looks like this, the server I am concerned with is server4-vn01.cifs.

```
/- /etc/server.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
/- /etc/server2.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
/- /etc/server3.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
/- /etc/server4-vn01.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
```

The mount points look like this

```
/etc/server4-vn01.cifs on /ql/mnt/client-21b type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=15420,timeout=400,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=377305956)
/etc/server4-vn01.cifs on /ql/mnt/client-85 type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=15420,timeout=400,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=377305956)
/etc/server4-vn01.cifs on /ql/mnt/client-uat type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=15420,timeout=400,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=377305956)
/etc/server4-vn01.cifs on /ql/mnt/client-21a type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=15420,timeout=400,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=377305956)
```

What I do not see here is where autofs is pointing to a directory on server4-vn01.cifs, all of the mount points point to the same place /etc/server4-vn01.cifs.  How do the mounts know which share path to hit on server4-vn01.cifs.  I understand that /- treats all mounts like one path?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the /etc/server.cifs are text files holding numerous server\share and mount info

```
    /- /etc/server.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
    /- /etc/server2.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
    /- /etc/server3.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
    /- /etc/server4-vn01.cifs --timeout=400 --ghost
```